# CollapsingToolbarLayout | Scrolling and layout issues

Tags: android, xml, material-design, android-design-library, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

### Related Questions

[CollapsingToolbarLayout | Scrolling and layout issues 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30902449/collapsingtoolbarlayout-scrolling-and-layout-issues-2)

### Question

I have been working with the `Android Support Design Library` and successfully implemented the `CoordinatorLayout` that causes the `Toolbar` and `TabLayout` to scroll out of view when scrolling. This works very well, so I figured I would try my luck with the new `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.

In a seperate activity, I have been having issue-after-issue with implementing `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. I am, as they say, close but no cigar.

I want to use 2 different fragments

1. **Header Image** (Currently just an `ImageView`)
2. **"Scrollable" content** (actually content isn't really scrollable, but I forced it will long Lorem Ipsum text for testing)

I had built one example of this layout by myself, but could not get it working after many tries. Finally, I found this [enter image description here][5] and modified it to get to the point I am now

## Issues

**Note:** I don't know if these are caused by 1 thing (dominoes effect), or if these are individual. Also, I have looked at quite a few related questions, but none seem to have any of these issues.

1. `Scrollable Content` is shown above the Header Image
2. `Scrollable Content` is not anchored to the bottom of the `Header Image`
3. On Scrolling of `Scrollable Content` it will scroll the `Header Image` seemingly randomly of either:

   - `Just right` and follows the speed of the finger (perfect)
   - `Too fast` and will animate the `Header Image` off the screen by moving my finger the height of 1 line of text
   - Also on `Scroll down`, the 2 above effects happen along with a 3rd effect

     - `Instant` or `Near instant` "animation" of showing the `Header Image` at full width

***Edit:** These below are asked in another question!! [The above had **1** simple fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30900320/2333021)*

4. <del>The `CollapsingToolbarLayout` does not allow me to expand the `Toolbar` to see the **full** `Header Image`</del>

   - <del>It shows a majority of the image, but not all. `Top` is cut, but the bottom is visible.</del>
5. <del>The `Toolbar` is set to `Pin` but it is hidden when scrolling</del>

   - <del>Just the `Header Image` should disappear</del>

## Code

### General Layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            <ImageView/> <!-- Will be a fragment later -->

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

        <fragment/>  <!-- Not a scrolling fragment layout -->

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

### Layout.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="16dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/download"

                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"

                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/detail"
            android:name="<package>.<fragment_name>"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

1 [image]
2 [image]
3 [image]

4 [image]
5 [image]
6 [image]

Comment: If any individual issue does have a related question on here, then I will modify the question to remove that issue :). I am looking at getting pictures uploaded to show the issues

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to your `NestedScrollView` - this marks the class which should be positioned below the `AppBarLayout` (and hence, below the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`).

Comment: OK...it works.  I will modify this question, and create a new question on the other issues.

Comment: I want to add a specific comment. `app:layout_behavior` is not displayed in the auto-complete; only 5 are displayed. 2 for `background`-related, 2 for `padding`-related, and 1 for `theme`

Comment: Do you know why the `back arrow` is not displaying?? This is a 2 activity app, and this activity is the child activity

Comment: I'd compare your `onCreate()` to that found in one of the design library's sample projects: [Cheesesquare](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/support/android/designlibdemo/CheeseDetailActivity.java#L44-L46)

Comment: I have created another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30902449/collapsingtoolbarlayout-scrolling-and-layout-issues-2. If you know anymore answers, then I will be happy to give you more points :)