# CollapsingToolbarLayout | Scrolling and layout issues 2

Tags: android, xml, material-design, android-design-library, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

### Related Questions

[CollapsingToolbarLayout | Scrolling and layout issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30899771/collapsingtoolbarlayout-scrolling-and-layout-issues)

### Backgroud

I want to use 2 different fragments that will allow me to change the layout based on orientation and screen size

1. **Header Image** (Currently just an `ImageView`)
2. **Scrollable content**

## Issues

1. The `CollapsingToolbarLayout` does not allow me to expand the `Toolbar` to see the **full** `Header Image`

   - It shows a majority of the image, but not all. `Top` is cut, but the bottom is visible.
2. The `Toolbar` is set to `Pin` but it is hidden when scrolling

   - Just the `Header Image` should disappear, but instead my whole Appbar gets hidden
3. When scrolling to view the `Expanded Toolbar` there is an empty view until the `Expanded Toolbar` reaches its max height.

   - After both the `Expanded Toolbar` and the `Toolbar` itself become hidden
4. The `Up Arrow` does not show up in the `Toolbar`

## Code

### Layout.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="16dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/download"

                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"

                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/anim_toolbar"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/detail"
            android:name="<package>.<fragment_name>"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

### OnCreate

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);

    final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.anim_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
    collapsingToolbar.setTitle("Avengers: Age of Ultron");

}
```

1 [image]
2 [image]
3 [image]

4 [image]
5 [image]
6 [image]

Comment: Adding `exitUntilCollapsed` to the CollapsingToolbarLayout should fix one point at least.

Comment: Other thing you can remove is `layout_below` on the NestedScrollView.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

#### Question 1

Add `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to your `AppBarLayout`, `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, and to your `ImageView`.

I'm guessing a part of your image is below the status bar (due to these lines being missing) which is why you can't see the top of the image.

#### Question 2

`collapseMode="pin"` only affects how the Toolbar reacts to collapsing (hence why it is called `collapseMode` and not `scrollFlags`).

In almost **all** cases when using `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, you should be using `scroll|exitUntilCollapsed` for your `scrollFlags` - this keeps the collapsed Toolbar visible even when you scroll downward.

#### Question 3

This is due to using `scroll|enterAlways`. Change your flags as per #2

#### Question 4

As mentioned in the answer to your related question, you need to call `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` to show the Up button:

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.test);

  final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.anim_toolbar);
  setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

  CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar =
      (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
  collapsingToolbar.setTitle("Avengers: Age of Ultron");
}
```

Comment: OK, these fixed most of the issues... **except Q4** as the back arrow is NOT showing. I figured Q2 and Q3 where linked

Comment: NOTE: I had to do your fixes to **Q1 and Q2/3 at the same time**. Individually they cause layout issues. I think that was my issue before.

Comment: Also, I think some of the image is hidden behind the status bar, maybe I can set it to tranparent....got to look at how to do that.....

Comment: Alright, Google Android Developer Advocate!! Is my Q4 related to this known bug ...  https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175240.  Actually, I do remember seeing the **App Bar Action Overflow icon** before. With some changes, it disappeared, but I don't know what that change was. Maybe now with your suggestion, the back navigation and action overflow will appear???

Comment: I have a problem my layout is not scrolling even after following this complete post

Comment: @ChristopherRucinski Hi... to your Q4, I've just had similar problem and solved it by adding "android:fitsSystemWindows="true" to the Toolbar.

Comment: on collapse i want to set the background image as the home icon image is it possible

Comment: I'd like to add that dont set `setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)` for the Toolbar otherwise the title disappears. Only set `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`

Comment: @ianhanniballake : how to set collapsingToolbar.setTitle as two line . Ultron in one line and online in another line

Answer (score 0):

Remove `app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"` from your layout XML in `CollapsingToolBarLayout` tag. It will show the back button in toolbar