# 2 days ago XML Layout ran perfectly, now (with no structural change) it gives me errors?

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, runtime-error, android-support-library

Two days ago, I posted [the following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30902449/collapsingtoolbarlayout-scrolling-and-layout-issues-2). While there were issues, it still ran - I could test the code on my phone still. However, with no major changes to the code (and definitely no structural changes), the program will refuse to run when I get to my Second Activity and crashes.

Luckily, I had posted all of my XML code for that Activity in the linked question.

### Error (Warnings actually)

1. `Element fragment is not allowed here`
2. `Element ImageView is not allowed here`

**How can this be??** This was working code that I ran on my phone, and now it is giving me a long list of error messages and I cannot run my second Activity, but I can run my first Activity.

**Detail**

```
This inspection highlights unallowed XML tags in Android resource files and AndroidManifest.xml
```

### Extra Information

1. I updated my IDE from `Android Studio 1.3 preview 4` to `preview 5` since posting the linked question

## Code

### Ran 2 days ago

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="16dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/download"

                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"

                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/anim_toolbar"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/detail"
            android:name="<package>.<fragment_name>"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

### Not working today

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <!-- HERE....ERROR -->
            <ImageView  
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/download"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:contentDescription="Movie Poster"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/anim_toolbar"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

            <!-- HERE....ERROR -->
            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/movie_detail"
                android:name="com.udacity.rucinskic.spotify_streamer.movies.fragments.MovieOverviewFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:layout="@layout/fragment_movie_detail" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

### OnCreateView

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movie_poster, container, false);

    TextView relaseYear = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.movie_release_year);
    RatingBar rating = (RatingBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.movie_rating);
    TextView overview = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.movie_overview);

    DetailedMovie movie = getMovie();

    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy", Locale.US);

    relaseYear.setText(format.format(movie.getDateRelease()));
    rating.setRating(movie.getRating());
    overview.setText(movie.getOverview());

    return rootView;

}
```

EDIT

### Stack Trace

```
    Process: com.udacity.rucinskic.spotify_streamer, PID: 27320
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.udacity.rucinskic.spotify_streamer/com.udacity.rucinskic.spotify_streamer.SecondaryActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #66: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2712)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2777)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:179)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1462)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5972)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #66: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:770)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at com.udacity.rucinskic.spotify_streamer.SecondaryActivity.onCreate(SecondaryActivity.java:21)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2777)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:179)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1462)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5972)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad class: class java.util.GregorianCalendar
            at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:296)
            at java.text.Format.format(Format.java:93)
            at com.udacity.rucinskic.spotify_streamer.movies.fragments.MovieOverviewFragment.onCreateView(MovieOverviewFragment.java:35)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:924)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1116)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1218)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2170)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:300)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.callActivityOnCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:838)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.callActivityOnCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:34)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:826)
            at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:732)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at com.udacity.rucinskic.spotify_streamer.SecondaryActivity.onCreate(SecondaryActivity.java:21)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2777)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:179)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1462)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5972)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Comment: Is this a bug in `Preview 5`?

Comment: One very obvious difference is the non-working xml contains the opening declaration line, a requirement of [well-formed xml](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-valid). Not at all familiar with android development but browsers even mobile ones can render xml files differently even ones not well-formed.

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` This?? This line is in all my layout resource files. All of them. I must not have copied that into the "working" xml

Comment: Try Inavlidate caches and Restart Android Studio by
FIle > Invalidate Caches and restart

Comment: Also post MovieOverviewFragment.java onCreateView()

Comment: Invalidate Caches / Restart - did not work. I will post onCreateView

Comment: This is the cause of your inflation error: 'Bad class: class java.util.GregorianCalendar'.  Why this bad class error suddenly occurs, I don't know. Try googling that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24041513/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-bad-class-class-java-util-gregoriancalendar

Comment: ummm...the issue was a copy-paste issue. I should have had the correct XML `R.layout.fragment_movie_detail` ㅡㅡ

Comment: I think you should check    **atcom.udacity.rucinskic.spotify_streamer.SecondaryActivity.onCreate(SecondaryActivity.java:21)**

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Try exchanging the ImageView to an android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView. It solved the problem for me!

Answer (score 0):

**TRY TO:**

- SET NEW BUILD TOOLS IN GRADLE IN APP MODULE
- SET NEW PLUGIN IN PROJECT
- CHECK FOR DEPENDENCIES OF SUPPORT LIBRARIES
- INVALIDATE CACHE

project 
[image]

app module
[image]

support dependiences in app module
[image]
**i tried it myself & i don't have any problem**

[image]

Comment: Did you have an error before doing this with my code?

Comment: i had allready set my project to new build tools before i  add yr code

Comment: @christopher-rucinski  check my edit (for support libs also)

Comment: No I didn't. The error and warnings are separate issues. This question was on the XML warnings. I fixed the errors, not the warnings. Your fixes did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. first close your project and then **import** it on android studio again. It solved my problem.